# Correct location for ESAPI.properties under web project

Tags: java, eclipse, esapi

I added a OWASP ESAPI library to my project. And currently I'm stuck with a problem where to locate `ESAPI.properties` file. This project later should be deployed on few servers to which I don't have an access. So in my opinion there is no way to customize`org.owasp.esapi.resources` variable and I can't put it under user home directory. So the only place where I can put this file is `SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory` but where is it? I have already tried to put these files:

```
.esapi/ESAPI.properties
esapi/ESAPI.properties
ESAPI.properties
```

Into these locations:

```
$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/<MY_PROJECT>/
$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/<MY_PROJECT>/WEB-INF
$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/<MY_PROJECT>/WEB-INF/classes
$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/<MY_PROJECT>/META-INF
```

But in all of these places I get an error:
`Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: .esapi\ESAPI.properties`

So where I should locate this file? It's a legacy project(just *Eclipse Project* without Maven) and it's structure is pretty ugly. There is no such directory like `/src/main/resources` where in my opinion this `ESAPI.properties` file should be located. I have created this directory, but where finally this file should be after deployment a WAR archive to Tomcat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ESAPI.properties` file should reside in a `CLASSPATH` under the `esapi` directory.

So let's say you have a module which is deployed into war in any of the 2 forms: as a jar, or exploded as classes.
Just create a directory inside the source of a module where you use the OWASP ESAPI 3rd party.

From eclipse perspective the file just need to be in the `CLASSPATH` regardless whether you use maven or not. When using maven, maven `resources` directory is converted as eclipse `sources` directory by `m2eclipse` plugin.

Example (using eclipse standard source structure):

```
src
|---com
|   |---module
|   |   |---SomeClass.java
|---esapi
|   |---ESAPI.properties
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately it looks like this structure doesn't work too. I just tried to build a war file in this way. In WAR file and in deployed folder I see ESAPI config files in same directory as my classes(/WEB-INF/classes). Classes root folder is `com` as it should be. And there are `esapi/ESAPI.properties` file. But I still see `Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: .esapi\ESAPI.properties` error message.

Comment: which version of esapi do you use?

Comment: OWASP ESAPI v2.1.0
It loads config files fine from my home directory.

Comment: UPD: Finally it works. Configured as you wrote above. I really not sure why it didn't work before. The only thing I change was excluding tests from a build path. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help. It describes the search order implemented in ESAPI 2.x to find the ESAPI.properties file:
http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultSecurityConfiguration.html

I think that documentation is fairly up-to-date, but you can find details of how it is implemented in the loadConfiguration() method of DefaultSecurityConfiguration.java which you can find here:

https://static.javadoc.io/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.0.1/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultSecurityConfiguration.html

Hope that helps. -kevin

Comment: My bad; when I answered, that link was still available. ESAPI moved to GitHub. Check out https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/esapi-2.1.0.1/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultSecurityConfiguration.java instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just a minor update that may be relevant. Looks like the 2.1.0.1 release accidentally broke the previous 2.x search order (in order to support XML configuration properties for ESAPI). This will be fixed in the (as-yet-to-be-determined) ESAPI point release. See [ESAPI GitHub issue 397](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/issues/397) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded `ESAPI 2.5` and added the `ESAPI.properties`, `esapi-java-logging.properties` and `validation.properties` files in the "`src`" ddirectory. No older structure, just there. eclipse IDE updates any changes on thos files to `WEB-INF/classes` directory and it worked for me