# How to use ESAPI Logger in an Android Native or Corodva Application

Tags: android, native, owasp, esapi, veracode

I am new to ESAPI and I have added esapi-2.0.1 jar to my Android app,was able to call any of the ESAPI methods.However, I am getting Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load ESAPI.properties as a classloader resource Error.My concern is it possible to use ESAPI for any android apps and if Yes then where to locate ESAPI.properties in an App.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS:This is my first question on stackoverflow.com pardon me if I did not follow any of the rules .

Update:There is a similar question looking for an answer 
[can we use owasp-ESAPI for logging android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590337/can-we-use-owasp-esapi-for-logging-android-application/46947439?noredirect=1#comment80842533_46947439)

Update 1:Sample code

```
   'String val = "twenty-one%0a%0aINFO:+User+logged+out%3dbadguy";
    val = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(val);
    try {

        int value = Integer.parseInt(val);

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Log.v("ESAPI", "Failed to parse val = " + val);

    }'
```

Comment: First off, the most updated version is 2.1.0.1.  2.0.1 has some security vulnerabilities.

Comment: And please provide some example code

Comment: @avgvstvs Thanks ,updated with Update 1: sample code I am trying in my Android app

Comment: @avgvstvs Hi I updated with sample code,my aim is to avoid Improper Output Neutralization for Logs CWE ID 117 .Thanks